# How can I transfer this Jquery function into a react function?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, css-transforms

## My problem is I don't know how to implement the Jquery code into a react app

---

### This is an alternating side coming in transform

*I regularly use this code in my applications to add a little motion to the page, but I obviously can't use Jquery in react so how would I go about getting the same functionality in to a react app*

---

> **Html Code**
>
> ```html
> <div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
> <div class="box-wrapper loading"><div class="box"></div></div>
> ```
>
> **CSS Code**
>
> ```css
> body {
>  overflow-x: hidden;
> }
> .box-wrapper {
>  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
>  transition-duration: 600ms;
> }
> .box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) {
>  transform: translate(100%);
> }
> .box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) {
>  transform: translate(-100%);
> }
> ```
>
> ### Issue:
>
> **Javascript Code**
>
> ```js
> $(".box-wrapper").each(function (index, element) {
>  setTimeout(function () {
>    element.classList.remove("loading");
>  }, index * 600);
> });
> ```

Comment: A "naive" solution would be to put the jQuery code in the `componentDidMount` of your "Root" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached a simplistic example of how you can achieve the above functionality via React.

```js
// Your entry component: App

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const boxArray = ["Box1", "Box2"];
  return (
    <>
      {boxArray.map((box, index) => {
        return <WrapperItem box={box} timeout={index * 600} key={index} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const WrapperItem = ({ box, timeout }) => {
  const [loadingClass, setLoadingClass] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadingClass(false);
    }, timeout);
  }, [timeout]);

  return (
    <div className={`boxWrapper ${loadingClass ? "loading" : ""}`}>
      <div className="box">
        <p>{box}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```css
// Place this in index.css

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.boxWrapper {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}
.boxWrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translate(100%);
}
.boxWrapper.loading:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

This can be further optimized / refactored based upon your requirement, but this gives you a basic idea of how to accomplish with React what you have been doing with jQuery.

I would suggest you to have a look at [React Transition Groups](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) package, to have more granular control over transitions in React, when you start thinking of improving your initial functionality.